# Haskell new line not working

Tags: haskell, newline

Been messing around for about 20 minutes now trying to get the new line working however it always shows in GHCI as a single line.

Here is what I enter into GHCi:

```
displayFilm ("Skyfall",["Daniel Craig", "Judi Dench", "Ralph Fiennes"], 2012, ["Bill", "Olga", "Zoe", "Paula", "Megan", "Sam", "Wally"])
```

Here is what is printed:

`"Skyfall----------\n Cast: Daniel Craig, Judi Dench, Ralph Fiennes\n Year: 2012\n Fans: 7\n"`

```
displayList :: [String] -> String
displayList [] = ""
displayList [x] = x ++ "" ++  displayList []
displayList (x:xs) = x ++ ", " ++ displayList xs


displayFilm :: Film -> String
displayFilm (title, cast, year, fans) = 
    title ++ "----------" ++
    "\n Cast: " ++ (displayList cast) ++
    "\n Year: " ++ (show year) ++
    "\n Fans: " ++ show (length fans) ++ "\n"
```

Comment: If I see another question about this assignment, I'm going to snap...

Comment: Just be glad that someone is giving out an assignment that helps people learn Haskell. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To print a string as it is, without escaping special characters, use:

```
putStr string
```

or

```
putStrLn string
```

if you want an extra newline at the end. In you case, you are probably looking for

```
putStr (displayFilm (....))
```

Why is this needed? In GHCi, if you evaluate an expression `s` the result will be printed as if running `print s` (unless it has type `IO something` -- forget about this special case). If `e` is a string, `print` *escapes* all the special characters and output the result. This is because `print` is meant to output a string whose syntax follows the one in Haskell expressions. For numbers, this is the usual decimal notation. For strings, we get quotes and escaped characters.

Comment: Is there a way that I can use "\n"?

Comment: @kmil You can use it as this: `putStr "aa\nbb"`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant **with** escaping special characters, not without.

Comment: @gragas Actually, `putStr` does not escape anything. E.g. if `string` contains a newline, it gets printed as a newline and not as the character `\` followed by `n`. Instead, `print` does escape special chars.

Answer (score 2):

When you type an expression into GHC, it displays it using `print`. Calling `print` on a string shows its content but does not evaluate escape sequences:

```
> print "line1\nline"
"line1\nline2"
```

Note the quotes.

To display the string as you desire, use `putStr` or `putStrLn` (the latter will append a newline).

```
> putStr "line1\nline2"
line1
line2
```