# How to output a 2 dimensional list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to output this 2D list with a line break. I have tried some methods but they do not seem to work. Please assist me. Thanks

My code:

```
list = [[' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ',' '],
        [' ','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*',' '],
        ['*',' ','*',' ','*',' ',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*',' ',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*'],
        ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'],
        [' ',' ','1',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','2',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','3',' ',' ']]

num :: [Int] -> String
num x = case x of
  []   -> []
  x:xs -> list!!x ++ "\n" ++ num xs
```

I output I get:

```
Prelude-> num [0,1,2,3,4]
"  *      *      *  \n * *    * *    * * \n* * *  * * *  * * *\n-------------------\n  1      2      3  \n"
```

The output I want:

```
Prelude-> num [0,1,2,3,4]
  *      *      *  
 * *    * *    * * 
* * *  * * *  * * *
-------------------
  1      2      3
```

Comment: [unlines](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:unlines)?

Comment: simply `putStr $ num [0..4]` and you'll get expected result. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089117/haskell-new-line-not-working

Comment: @qxg Thanks. That really helped

Comment: Use `unlines list`, you don't need `num` at all. But if the objective is to build the expected output with an arbitrary height, then you don't need `list` but you will have to change your definition of `num`.